# Get current CPU usage on Deno

Tags: cpu-usage, deno

There are `process.cpuUsage()` function on `NodeJS` and `Deno.memoryUsage()` function to get memory usage on `Deno`

also there are a process module for Deno at https://deno.land/std@0.123.0/node/process.ts
but its not including something like `.cpuUsage()`

so is there are a way to get current cpu usage on `Deno` ?

Comment: You'll likely need (and will prefer for performance reasons) a native plugin for this (see [FFI API](https://deno.land/manual@v1.18.1/runtime/ffi_api)).

Comment: Which OS platform are you targeting (win, mac, or linux)?

Comment: @jsejcksn all of them

Comment: Do you have Node.js installed and available in your `PATH` on the devices in question? (e.g. Can you run `node -e "console.log('hello')"` and you'll see `hello` on the next `stdout` line?)

Comment: Also, can you share your use case for this: how do you plan to use a single point instantaneous sample of current CPU load? Most abstractions provide averaged values (e.g. avg over last `1`/`5`/`15` min)

Comment: @jsejcksn I will use this for logging current system usage to the database on every request, so I will be able to know which API path caused to system crash

Answer (score 2):

At the time I write this answer, it's not natively possible to obtain sampled CPU load data in Deno.

If you want this data now, you can get it one of two ways:

1. Using the [Foreign Function Interface API](https://deno.land/manual@v1.18.1/runtime/ffi_api)
2. Use the [subprocess API](https://deno.land/manual@v1.18.1/examples/subprocess)

I'll provide a code sample below for how to get the data by installing Node.js and using the second method:

---

`node_eval.ts`:

```ts
type MaybePromise<T> = T | Promise<T>;
type Decodable = Parameters<TextDecoder['decode']>[0];

const decoder = new TextDecoder();

async function trimDecodable (decodable: MaybePromise<Decodable>): Promise<string> {
  return decoder.decode(await decodable).trim();
}

/**
 * Evaluates the provided script using Node.js (like
 * [`eval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval))
 * and returns `stdout`.
 *
 * Uses the resolved version of `node` according to the host environemnt.
 *
 * Requires `node` to be available in `$PATH`.
 * Requires permission `--allow-run=node`.
 */
export async function evaluateUsingNodeJS (script: string): Promise<string> {
  const cmd = ['node', '-e', script];
  const proc = Deno.run({cmd, stderr: 'piped', stdout: 'piped'});

  const [{code}, stderr, stdout] = await Promise.all([
    proc.status(),
    trimDecodable(proc.stderrOutput()),
    trimDecodable(proc.output()),
  ]);

  if (code !== 0) {
    const msg = stderr ? `\n${stderr}` : '';
    throw new Error(`The "node" subprocess exited with a non-zero status code (${code}). If output was emitted to stderr, it is included below.${msg}`);
  }

  return stdout;
}
```

`mod.ts`:

```ts
import {evaluateUsingNodeJS} from './node_eval.ts';

export const cpuTimesKeys: readonly (keyof CPUTimes)[] =
  ['user', 'nice', 'sys', 'idle', 'irq'];

export type CPUTimes = {
  /** The number of milliseconds the CPU has spent in user mode */
  user: number;

  /**
   * The number of milliseconds the CPU has spent in nice mode
   * 
   * `nice` values are POSIX-only.
   * On Windows, the nice values of all processors are always `0`.
   */
  nice: number;

  /** The number of milliseconds the CPU has spent in sys mode */
  sys: number;

  /** The number of milliseconds the CPU has spent in idle mode */
  idle: number;

  /** The number of milliseconds the CPU has spent in irq mode */
  irq: number;
};

export type CPUCoreInfo = {
  model: string;

  /** in MHz */
  speed: number;

  times: CPUTimes;
};

/**
 * Requires `node` to be available in `$PATH`.
 * Requires permission `--allow-run=node`.
 */
export async function sampleCPUsUsingNodeJS (): Promise<CPUCoreInfo[]> {
  const script = `console.log(JSON.stringify(require('os').cpus()));`;
  const stdout = await evaluateUsingNodeJS(script);

  try {
    return JSON.parse(stdout) as CPUCoreInfo[];
  }
  catch (ex) {
    const cause = ex instanceof Error ? ex : new Error(String(ex));
    throw new Error(`The "node" subprocess output couldn't be parsed`, {cause});
  }
}

/**
 * (Same as `CPUCoreInfo`, but) aliased in recognition of the transfromation,
 * in order to provide JSDoc info regarding the transformed type
 */
export type TransformedCoreInfo = Omit<CPUCoreInfo, 'times'> & {
  /** Properties are decimal percentage of total time */
  times: Record<keyof CPUCoreInfo['times'], number>;
};

/** Converts each time value (in ms) to a decimal percentage of their sum */
export function coreInfoAsPercentages (coreInfo: CPUCoreInfo): TransformedCoreInfo {
  const timeEntries = Object.entries(coreInfo.times) as [
    name: keyof CPUCoreInfo['times'],
    ms: number,
  ][];

  const sum = timeEntries.reduce((sum, [, ms]) => sum + ms, 0);

  for (const [index, [, ms]] of timeEntries.entries()) {
    timeEntries[index][1] = ms / sum;
  }

  const times = Object.fromEntries(timeEntries) as TransformedCoreInfo['times'];
  return {...coreInfo, times};
}
```

`example.ts`:

```ts
import {
  coreInfoAsPercentages,
  cpuTimesKeys,
  sampleCPUsUsingNodeJS,
  type CPUCoreInfo,
} from './mod.ts';

function anonymizeProcessorAttributes <T extends CPUCoreInfo>(coreInfoArray: T[]): T[] {
  return coreInfoArray.map(info => ({
    ...info,
    model: 'REDACTED',
    speed: NaN,
  }));
}

// Get the CPU info
const cpuCoreInfoArr = await sampleCPUsUsingNodeJS();

// Anonymizing my personal device details (but you would probably not use this)
const anonymized = anonymizeProcessorAttributes(cpuCoreInfoArr);

// JSON for log data
const jsonLogData = JSON.stringify(anonymized);
console.log(jsonLogData);

// Or, for purely visual inspection,
// round the percentages for greater scannability...

const roundedPercentages = anonymized.map(coreInfo => {
  const asPercentages = coreInfoAsPercentages(coreInfo);
  for (const key of cpuTimesKeys) {
    asPercentages.times[key] = Math.round(asPercentages.times[key] * 100);
  }
  return asPercentages;
});

// and log in tabular format
console.table(roundedPercentages.map(({times}) => times));
```

In the console:

```
% deno run --allow-run=node example.ts
[{"model":"REDACTED","speed":null,"times":{"user":2890870,"nice":0,"sys":2290610,"idle":17913530,"irq":0}},{"model":"REDACTED","speed":null,"times":{"user":218270,"nice":0,"sys":188200,"idle":22687790,"irq":0}},{"model":"REDACTED","speed":null,"times":{"user":2509660,"nice":0,"sys":1473010,"idle":19111680,"irq":0}},{"model":"REDACTED","speed":null,"times":{"user":221630,"nice":0,"sys":174140,"idle":22698480,"irq":0}},{"model":"REDACTED","speed":null,"times":{"user":2161140,"nice":0,"sys":1086970,"idle":19846200,"irq":0}},{"model":"REDACTED","speed":null,"times":{"user":221800,"nice":0,"sys":157620,"idle":22714800,"irq":0}},{"model":"REDACTED","speed":null,"times":{"user":1905230,"nice":0,"sys":897140,"idle":20291910,"irq":0}},{"model":"REDACTED","speed":null,"times":{"user":224060,"nice":0,"sys":146460,"idle":22723700,"irq":0}}]
┌───────┬──────┬──────┬─────┬──────┬─────┐
│ (idx) │ user │ nice │ sys │ idle │ irq │
├───────┼──────┼──────┼─────┼──────┼─────┤
│     0 │   13 │    0 │  10 │   78 │   0 │
│     1 │    1 │    0 │   1 │   98 │   0 │
│     2 │   11 │    0 │   6 │   83 │   0 │
│     3 │    1 │    0 │   1 │   98 │   0 │
│     4 │    9 │    0 │   5 │   86 │   0 │
│     5 │    1 │    0 │   1 │   98 │   0 │
│     6 │    8 │    0 │   4 │   88 │   0 │
│     7 │    1 │    0 │   1 │   98 │   0 │
└───────┴──────┴──────┴─────┴──────┴─────┘
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use https://deno.land/std@0.123.0/node/os.ts where `cpus()` gives `CPUCoreInfo[]`

Comment: how can i understand how many percentage is the cpu usage

Comment: Guess https://deno.land/std@0.123.0/node/os.ts#L29 give ms per type (sys, user, etc) but I guess you want it for the Deno process only instead of "Get current CPU usage".

Comment: This is wrong. The values of that function [are hardcoded to zeros](https://deno.land/std@0.123.0/node/os.ts#L118-L132). Try running it in your console to see for yourself: `deno eval --unstable --print "(await import('https://deno.land/std@0.123.0/node/os.ts')).cpus()"`

Comment: @ClemensTolboom no i want get current CPU usage of system not only deno process

Comment: According to https://deno.land/std@0.123.0/node `os` is **partly** and it is a `node compatibility` module as a whole. You can check what works by follow the test instructions maybe. 6 days ago https://github.com/denoland/deno/pull/13475 got in. Guess we need deno v1.18